# Twitter bootstrap complete list of icons with label

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new using the excellent stuff of css twitter bootstrap and having a problem, I'm not able to find a complete list of all
the icons with a meaningful label.
I've just googling without no change.
Can you give me a link, please?

Comment: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#icons

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#images working link

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use native twitter bootstrap icons: [twitter bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#icons)

Or [font awesome](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/) which has many more icons.

Perhaps there are some ready-made fonts that can be used, but I only know this one.

Here you can read how to use them: [w3resource](http://www.w3resource.com/twitter-bootstrap/icons.php)

So you can use your own icons. How to do this: [create custom icons](http://favbulous.com/post/1006/create-custom-icons-for-twitter-bootstrap-easily)

Comment: Also you should change your text to read "Or font awesome which has many more icons." Instead of "Or font awesome which have one more icons." That's not really clear. It has a lot more than one. In fact at this moment it has about 110 more icons, 249 in total.

Comment: Font Awesome is a great gem!!

Answer (score 3):

I found http://glyphsearch.com/ extremely helpful. Some icons have more than one tag, and it let's you search over tags.

Answer (score 2):

For Bootstrap 3, check the official documentation http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons.

If you want the code for the icons, this is the best resource I've found: http://bootply.com/61521.

Note that the HTML changed a bit; instead of using  tags, use  tags and the .icon .icon-* and .icon-white classes are now .glyphicon, .glyphicon-*, .glyphicon-white.

EDIT: Bootstrap has updated their documentation, you can now find the whole list at http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#icons